# Alert not working in Ajax Success Function

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a problem that I get the data from contact us form and send it to PHP file via ajax to send an email for the person who submits but I need to display a verification message to him on the site and the alert or any code in the success function doesn't work although the email goes through
here is My Function

```
    function SendMail(){
    // document.getElementById("loading").style.display = "block";
    var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
    var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
    var subject = document.getElementById("subject").value;
    var message = document.getElementById("message").value;
    var Sent = false;
    $.ajax({
      url:"SendMail.php",
      type:"post",
      dataType: "json",
      data: {type: "contact",name : name , email: email, subject: subject , message : message},
      success : function(data){
          alert("We Recieved Your Message and will get back as soon as possible");
      }

    });


}
```

Comment: Have you confirmed you have reached to `success` callback correctly using `console.log`?

Comment: it doesn't output anything !! and I really don't know why it doesn't enter in the Success function although everything goes well in the PHP file

Comment: The reason would happen is if the ajax were not successful, you can add callbacks that handle errors

Comment: Are you `echo json_encode($objectOrAssocArrayHere);`ing on your PHP page?

Comment: Add `error` callback inside ajax and see what error shows.

Comment: And don't use alert, _just_ use the Console API. It doesn't block the entire page, and can log anything and everything in an explorable fashion. Unlike `alert`, which is an all-round terrible hold over from 1998 and not to be used or talked about anymore.

Comment: Not I am just echoing json_encode("Good"); if there is no exceptions in the PHP file

Comment: as said twice already, add `error:` callback to debug errors

Comment: is SendMail.php something you wrote? perhaps you wrote it wrong

Comment: Error: SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unable to parse JSON string
this is the error I received when I added error call back

Comment: so, your PHP isn't responding with valid JSON - since you expect JSON (according to your dataType) - solved

Comment: Thanks man for your help I really appreciate it

Comment: Okay Guys I found where the problem is, PHPMailer echo a lot of echo statments so after removing them and just echoing "Good" it worked prefectly

Comment: @JaromandaX, your last comment was correct, but your previous comment cannot be substantiated. Comments redacted.